# Decrypt mp3 file using commoncrypto in iOS (mp3 file was encrypted using openssl)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, encryption, openssl

I have an encrypted MP3 file. The file was encrypted using the following openssl method

```
openssl enc -e -aes-128-cbc -K 00ff349830193845af43984758690213 -p -iv 0 -nosalt -in  input.mp3 -out output.mp3
```

Then I'm trying decrypt the file in my ios application as follows,

```
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]] ;
NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp3"];
NSData *key = [@"00ff349830193845af43984758690213" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *iv = [@"00000000000000000000000000000000" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSData *decryptData;

CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
size_t          cryptBytes = 0;    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:fileData.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                   kSecPaddingNone,
                   key.bytes,
                   kCCKeySizeAES128,
                   iv.bytes,
                   fileData.bytes,
                   fileData.length,
                   dataOut.mutableBytes,
                   dataOut.length,
                   &cryptBytes);

if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"CCCrypt status: %d", ccStatus);
}    
dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
decryptData = dataOut;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDECFile.mp3"];
[decrypt writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
```

Now I have the decrypted MP3 file in document directory, But its not playing and literally its a junk output. Please suggest me a way to get the desired output.

Comment: I would suggest you to try to en/decrypt a plain known text using the same toolchain - maybe the error becomes obvious that way.

Comment: Compare the original (encrypted) file with CC encrypted file in a HEX editor. If it looks pretty much the same (but some bytes at the end or start are different) you need to dig into: kSecPaddingNone (at the end) NSData *iv (file start).

Comment: @JonasSchnelli>> thanks for your support dude.. yes you are right..i found that the HEX values are different. And now i resolved this problem by using https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor for decryption.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Security/Security.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "RNEncryptor.h"
#import "RNDecryptor.h"
#import "RNOpenSSLEncryptor.h"
#import "RNOpenSSLDecryptor.h"

NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]] ;
NSString *filePath1 = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp3"]; //The encrypted mp3 file (with aPassword)
NSData *passEncryptedData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath1]; 
NSError *error;   
NSString *pass = @"aPassword";    
NSData *dataDecrypted = [RNOpenSSLDecryptor decryptData:passEncryptedData 
                                           withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                               password:pass
                                                  error:&error];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"passDecryptFile.mp3"]; //The Decrypted file saved here
[dataDecrypted writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
```

Comment: One important thing to remember is that the decryption in the above code is based on the kRNCryptorAES256Settings, so when you encrypt your file (like in Terminal) you must use the AES256 encryption option. Example on how to encrypt: openssl aes-256-cbc -in questions.plist -out questions.encr